# Can I hold a shared_ptr without knowing the type parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, std

I would like to hold a `shared_ptr` of a template class. However, I don't want to make the class B as a template class too. In my understanding, shared_ptr with any type will have the same memory layout. So I am wondering any workaround in this scenario?

```
template<T>
class A {
...
};

class B {
...
  std::shared_ptr<A<T>> ptr;
}
```

Comment: How about you use a base class for the templated class `A` and use that instead?

Comment: How are you planning on using `ptr` if you don't know the type of `*ptr`?

Comment: [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the type doesn't matter at all, `void` can be used.

```
template <typename>
class C {};

std::shared_ptr<void> p = std::make_shared<C<int>>();
```

Adding a monomorphic base class allows restricting the type that can be stored.

```
class AnyC {};

template <typename>
class C : public AnyC {};

std::shared_ptr<AnyC> p = std::make_shared<C<int>>();
```

If that base class has virtual methods they can be called through the pointer.

```
class AnyC {
    virtual void f();
};

template <typename>
class C : public AnyC {
    void f() override;
};

std::shared_ptr<AnyC> p = std::make_shared<C<int>>();
p->f();
```

Comment: Thanks! the base class method works well!